# Error when uploading the local server and endpoint in my test file (spec.js)

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress, mysql2

I have the following problem:

I'm automating tests using Cypress.
I created a local server, an endpoint and I always need to go up before my test and always close after my test.

**I tried one way but I get the following error:**

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./node_modules/mysql2/node_modules/lru-cache/dist/mjs/index.js 51:11
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (51:11)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|      length;
|      private constructor
>     static #constructing = false;
|     static create(max) {
|         const HeapCls = getUintArray(max);
 @ ./node_modules/mysql2/lib/parsers/parser_cache.js 3:12-32
 @ ./node_modules/mysql2/promise.js
```

Can anybody help me?

**My file that I upload to the server (index.js):**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const programmingLanguagesRouter = require("./routes/programmingLanguages");

app.use(express.json());

app.use(
    express.urlencoded({
        extended: true,
    })
);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: "ok" });
});

app.use("/programming-languages", programmingLanguagesRouter);

/* Error handler middleware */
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    const statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
    console.error(err.message, err.stack);
    res.status(statusCode).json({ message: err.message });
    return;
});

function test() {
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
}

module.exports = test();
```

**My test file that I need to upload to the server by calling the index.js file (test.spec.js):**

```
const xxxx = require('../../../../../../../../index.js');

describe("Calling the endpoint", async () => {
context("Test", () => {
 
it("Test", () => {

      xxxx.tes()

      cy.request({
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'accept': 'application/json'
        },

        url: 'localhost:3000/programming-languages'
      }).then((res) => {
        expect(res.status).to.equal(200);

      });
    });
});
});
```

When I call command "node index.js" the server starts successfully and I can access my endpoint.

The problem is trying to upload the server in my test file and shutting down right after.

can you help me?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Could someone help me?

Comment: You're not really uploading something, you need to start the server. And you don't need to "shut it down", it will do it on it's own.

Answer (score 6):

The code in the server index can only be run in NodeJs, but you have tried to pull it into the test which runs in the Browser context.

```js
// in test
const xxxx = require('../../../../../../../../index.js');

// but express.js does not work in the browser.
```

I don't know if the error you posted is caused by that, it actually looks like something else.

But the first thing to do is correct the server startup.

I recommend you read through this example and adapt it to your server index code.

[Cypress Introduction - Boot your server](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/introduction#Boot-your-server)

The essential bit is the **scripts** to start your server ***before you start Cypress***.

This is roughly what you need:

```js
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "/server/index.js",
    "cy:run": "cypress run",
    "test": "start-server-and-test start http://localhost:3030 cy:open"
  }
}
```

Comment: A.Givens, Hi!
No need to open a browser! It's all the same!
I did as per your suggestion. The server went up, however, the tests are not executed... It is stuck on the listening port...

Do you know what I could do?

Thanks